# Print the Cantor Set using recursion in C

Tags: c, recursion

I'm trying to print the [Cantor Set](http://earsketch.gatech.edu/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/cantor.jpeg) to the console using 'x', but I'm stuck at the 2nd recursion which no matter what I do, just doesn't execute.

The Idea is to first initialize the matrix using clearP() so I don't have to worry about the whitespaces. After that I load the array with 'x' chars using the depth as a [y] value.

To remove the middle segment on each line I use secondLength and smallerLength. Now the reason to use 2 recursive calls is, that for example on depth 1 it removes the middle part once, on depth 2 twice, on depth 3 four times and so on. However I just can't get the 2nd recursion to execute, which is why my output looks like [this](http://i61.tinypic.com/sgi9h0.jpg).

Any advice where I'm making mistakes?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define WIDTH 27
#define HEIGHT (int)(cbrt(WIDTH)+1)


void clearP(char p[WIDTH][HEIGHT]){
    int x, y;
    for(x = 0; x<WIDTH; x++){
        for (y=0;y<HEIGHT;y++){
            p[x][y] = ' ';
        }
    }
}

void printP(char p[WIDTH][HEIGHT]){
    int x, y;
    for(y = 0; y<HEIGHT; y++){
        for (x=0;x<WIDTH;x++){
            printf("%c",p[x][y]);
        }
            printf("\n");
    }
}

void cantor(char p[WIDTH][HEIGHT],int start,int end, int depth){
    int smallerLength = end / 3;                            
    int secondStart = start + (smallerLength * 2);

    for (int x = start; x<end ; x++){
            p[x][depth] = 'x';
    }

    if (depth == HEIGHT){
        return;
    }

    cantor(p, start, smallerLength, depth+1); 
    cantor(p, secondStart, smallerLength, depth+1);
    }

int main(){
char canvas[WIDTH][HEIGHT];
    clearP(canvas);
    cantor(canvas, 0, WIDTH, 0);
    printP(canvas);
}
```

Comment: Prof Böhlen will not like this!

Comment: Jimmy statuts: rustled.

Comment: beauty of SO is that it retains the old edits of your questions !

Answer (score 0):

I think you got your height and width mixed up in print.

try this

```
void printP(char p[WIDTH][HEIGHT]){
int x, y;
for(x = 0; x<HEIGHT; x++){
    for (y=0;y<WIDTH;y++){
        printf("%c",p[x][y]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I want to print line 0, then line 1, etc. So I need to have the outer forloop iterate over y and the inner forloop iterate over x.

Answer (score 0):

A point in [0, 1] is in the Cantor set if it's ternary representation doesn't contain any 1's (that is, only 0's and 2's). This observation allows you to output the d-level representation by looking at the first d digits of the fractional part of i/n in base 3, without needing arrays.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void cantor(int n, int d) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int in = 1;
        int x = i;
        for (int j = 0; j < d; j++) {
            in = in && !(3*x >= n && 3*x < 2*n);
            x = (3*x)%n;
        }
        putchar(in ? 'x' : ' ');
    }
    putchar('\n');
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    for (int d = 0; d < 5; d++) {
        cantor(81, d);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, that indeed is a genius and short method to print the Cantor set. Though I want to be able to store the Cantor set in an array using recursion, so that it is independent from the left-to-right top-down printing order.